# How to fetch all products from Amazon seller ID by using Amazon MWS API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-mws

With this API get_report_request_list, get_report, I am getting products response which is only ordered, many product remains whitch is still not order.

```
mws = MWS.new(:aws_access_key_id => access_key,
     :secret_access_key => secret_key,
     :seller_id => merchant_id,
     :marketplace_id => marketplace_id,
     :MWS_auth_token => mws_auth_token)


            mws = Mws.connect(
              merchant: merchant_id,
              access: access_key,
              secret: secret_key]
            )

response = mws.reports.get_report(:report_id => generated_report_id)
```

And With this API list_matching_products

```
mws = Mws.connect(
        merchant: merchant_id,
        access: access_key,
        secret: secret_key,
        MWS_auth_token: mws_auth_token,
      )

response = mws.products.list_matching_products(marketplace_id: marketplace_id,query: "1")
```

I only get 10 products response with this.

But, I need total products which is listed, Ordered one or Unordered One.

https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_GetReportRequestList.html
http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_IT/products/Products_ListMatchingProducts.html

If anybody knows which API, I can use to get all listed products.

Comment: Hi Vishwas you need to use Amazon Orders API in order to get all active listings.http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__ListingsReports

Comment: @Keyur Thanks for the comment, but with this i got those products which is already ordered, i want unordered also. order API gives those products which is in ordered list.

Answer (score 2):

The [Reports API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_RequestReport.html) is what you want and it looks like that's what you were using, but I don't see the report you were requesting, just that you requested a report.  Have a look at the report types here:

https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html

and use `RequestReport` to request report you want.  You probably want the `Inventory Report` or `Active Listings Report`.

You don't want to use the Products API for this, that will not return your inventory.